# Out-File does not show all my columns

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "DC=some,DC=website,DC=net" -Filter * -Properties Name,Created,whenChanged,LastLogonDate,Description,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion | Sort Description | Format-Table Name,Created,whenChanged,LastLogonDate,Description,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion -Wrap  | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\AD-Quick-Inventory.txt
```

The above code is what I want, but when outputted to a .txt file I only have 5 columns (stopping at description).

How do I allow for all the columns to be displayed.

I tried export-csv and it did export data I wanted, but it also exported a bunch of random properties I didn't select.

Comment: You have the -wrap parameter set. What happens if you remove that one? Also, are they maybe on multiple lines?

Comment: have you tried to pipe to Out-String -Width 4096 first before pipe to Out-File

Comment: Its funny you mentioned Out-String because I found an article yesterday after posting that covers this exact topic. https://poshoholic.com/2010/11/11/powershell-quick-tip-creating-wide-tables-with-powershell/

Comment: out-file also has a width parameter, so no need for out-string (i guess)

Answer (score 0):

Certain cmdLets can only be used at the end of the pipeline (Format-table, Out-File, Export-Csv). Once you use any of those cmdLets putting another after it will produce junk because the former has converted the object data to non-object data like strings, etc. If you replace `format-table` with `select-object` you will get a CSV with only the properties you've selected with `select-object`.

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "DC=some,DC=website,DC=net" -Filter * `
-Properties Name,Created,whenChanged,LastLogonDate,Description,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion `
| Select-Object -Property Name,Created,whenChanged,LastLogonDate,Description,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion `
| Sort Description | `
Export-Csv -Path AD-Quick-Inventory.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

How about piping your Get-ADComputer to csv like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "DC=some,DC=website,DC=net" -Filter * `
-Properties Name,Created,whenChanged,LastLogonDate,Description,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion `
| Select-Object -Property Name,Created,whenChanged,LastLogonDate,Description,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion `
| Sort Description   | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $path
```